# Confused between new and old Javascript syntax

Tags: node.js, lti

Following code is throwing a syntax error in node `v10.15.3`

```
var lti = require('library name');

var provider = lti.somemethod(some arguments)
// following line throw syntax error
provider.valid_request req, (err, isValid) ->
```

Comment: if you want to use to `arrow function` its `(arg1, arg2) => { //code block }` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions

Comment: `->` is not part of any old or new JavaScript syntax, it's [CoffeeScript](https://coffeescript.org/#introduction).

Answer (score 0):

Normal Javascript Syntax

```
function myFunc(arg1, arg2, arg3){
    // Func logic here
}
```

This function can be rewritten in ES6 syntax as following

```
const myFunc = (arg1, arg2, arg3) => {
    // Func Logic Here
}
```

I Assume that in your question, provider.valid_request is a function which takes in a callback function as an argument.

so you can write it as

```
provider.valid_request(req, (err, isValid) => {
    if(!err && isValid){
      // logic here
    }
})
```

Comment: Thanks, this solves my problem.    

provider.valid_request(req, function(err, isValid) {
// logic here
  });

Comment: hi @Punit Can you make this solution as user accepted